# Subscription app without Apple In App Purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription

I've created an app that has been twice rejected for not using Apple's In App Purchase program for creating subscriptions, and not allowing the user to use any portion of the app without a subscription. I've since gone through the app, and added the bare minimum I would like to allow the user to get for free, but I'm still confused on the subscription based model. I'd prefer to not use Apple's IAP, as they take 30% versus the 3% I would have to pay for my own credit card processing.

I can easily create a website with a payment form that would allow them to create an account and sign up for the subscription, I just want to make sure I am doing it correctly, as app review times right now are 7-10 days with each new build.

What I know:

- They cannot sign up or pay for the subscription within the app (hence
  creating a separate site with payment form)
- I cannot link out to the site to sign up for the subscription

My questions:

- I know companies like Netflix don't allow you to see their content without being signed in, but what about hiding functionality of the app? Will it pass review if I hide functionality of the app unless they are signed in?
- Can I link to the main site for my app, if that one of the site's pages is the sign up page?
- Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: 1. Yes. See "Go Reception" for iPad as an example.  2. no. 3. Maybe

Comment: So, as long as I say nothing about signing up or linking to the site from the app, I can turn off and on functionality within the app based on their subscription, correct?

Comment: Yes. That should be OK. Apple is the ultimate decision maker but I have seen lots of apps that are useless unless you have some account on some other system; Salesforce.com apps, expense apps and so on.